# Add TSL ASCII 2 Software Development Kit – for Android™ into ionic capacitor 4 project

Tags: ionic-framework, sdk, capacitor, rfid, capacitor-plugin

I am new to Ionic Capacitor, not sure how to integrate 3rd party native SDKs to ionic capacitor app.

We have native apps where we use "TSL ASCII 2 Software Development Kit" (https://www.tsl.com/downloads-packages/software-development-kits/) to read RFID Tags for iOS and Android. Now, we wanted to go with Capacitor implement same.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Use "TSL ASCII 2 Software Development Kit" in ionic capacitor app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom plugin using capacitor using those 3rd party native SDKs. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/creating-plugins